# Change name of heroku application

Tags: heroku, github, heroku-toolbelt

I just uploaded my application to heroku, when loading the web app in the web browser, the name of the application in the web browser tab is what i called it on my desktop "rails project", for production how could i change this so that it is a proper name, for example "website name"?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/renaming-apps

Comment: I tried this command, this changes the app name from "myapp.heroku.com" to "maybe.heroku.com". When opening a new tab a going to the website, it usually says the website name in the windows tab. that what i was looking to change

Comment: That has nothing to do with your app's name on Heroku and everything to do with what's in the HTML [`<title>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title) tag of whatever page you are looking at.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to change the name of your app itself on Heroku's platform, open your terminal and enter the following:

```
heroku apps:rename newname
```

If you want to change the title that appears in the browser tab, go to your application.html.erb or whatever your layout file is that contains the html doc type and header and enter the title like this:

```
<title>My New App Name</title>
```

If you want to change the domain name that you navigate to in your browser, you'll want to enter this on the command line:

```
heroku domains:add www.example.com
```

You'll need to add CNAME records to your DNS file that point to Heroku.  Their documentation explains it here:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains

Comment: I tried this command, this changes the app name from "myapp.heroku.com" to "maybe.heroku.com". When opening a new tab a going to the website, it usually says the website name in the windows tab. that what i was looking to change

Comment: I modified my original answer to cover three domain related questions about Heroku. Let me know if these help by accepting the answer or posting back.

Comment: thanks, the title tags needed to be changed... rookie mistake

Answer (score 0):

This is really so simple step. At least it  worked for me.

First of all go to your `heroku dashboard` and choose the app you want to rename. And there you just rename your application like you want.  Accept all of the warnings.

Secondly you go to your `.git` folder of your app folder  and then to the `config` file and open it in a **text editor** and at `url` change your app name exactly how you have renamed your `dashboard app` and *don't* *delete* the last `.git`. And `save` it.

Third and finally, you just choose the `directory` on your terminal and just upload your `heroku app`  like you did earlier.

```
heroku login
git init
git add.
git commit -m "your message"

git push heroku master
```

Comment: Can you change the name of the app that heroku created for you?